# Unable to install prey on ubuntu15.10

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I am trying to install prey on Ubuntu 15.10. I have downloaded `.deb` file from https://preyproject.com/download  but when I use

```
sudo dpkg -i prey_1.5.0_i386.deb
```

I receive the output:

```
(Reading database ... 363093 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack prey_1.5.0_i386.deb ...

Unpacking prey:i386 (1.5.0) over (1.5.0) ...

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of prey:i386:

 prey:i386 depends on sudo.

 prey:i386 depends on python.

 prey:i386 depends on python-gtk2.

 prey:i386 depends on scrot.

 prey:i386 depends on streamer.

 prey:i386 depends on mpg123.

 prey:i386 depends on dmidecode.

 prey:i386 depends on gksu.



dpkg: error processing package prey:i386 (--install):

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Errors were encountered while processing:

 prey:i386
```

When I try:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then this comes

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Correcting dependencies... Done

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

  giblib1:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libaudit1:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libcairo2:i386
  libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libdv4:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386
  libgnome-keyring0:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386
  libharfbuzz0b:i386 libid3tag0:i386 libimlib2:i386 libncursesw5:i386
  libpam-modules:i386 libpam0g:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386
  libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386
  libpython-stdlib:i386 libpython2.7-minimal:i386 libpython2.7-stdlib:i386
  libreadline6:i386 libstartup-notification0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-util1:i386 mpg123:i386 scrot:i386 sudo:i386

Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.

The following extra packages will be installed:
  giblib1:i386 libaudit1:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libid3tag0:i386
  libimlib2:i386 libpam-modules:i386 libpam0g:i386 libthai0:i386 mpg123:i386
  scrot:i386 sudo:i386

Suggested packages:

  libpam-doc:i386 jackd:i386 nas:i386 oss-compat:i386 oss4-base:i386

Recommended packages:

  update-motd:i386

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  prey:i386 sudo

The following NEW packages will be installed:

  giblib1:i386 libaudit1:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libid3tag0:i386
  libimlib2:i386 libpam-modules:i386 libpam0g:i386 libthai0:i386 mpg123:i386
  scrot:i386 sudo:i386

0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

1 not fully installed or removed.

Need to get 0 B/1,140 kB of archives.

After this operation, 14.4 MB disk space will be freed.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Preconfiguring packages ...

(Reading database ... 363092 files and directories currently installed.)

Removing prey:i386 (1.5.0) ...

Removing sudo (1.8.12-1ubuntu3) ...

You have asked that the sudo package be removed,

but no root password has been set.

Without sudo, you may not be able to gain administrative privileges.


If you would prefer to access the root account with su(1)

or by logging in directly,

you must set a root password with "sudo passwd".




If you have arranged other means to access the root account,

and you are sure this is what you want,

you may bypass this check by setting an environment variable 

(export SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE=yes).


Refusing to remove sudo.

dpkg: error processing package sudo (--remove):

 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:

 sudo

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried using

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

too but nothing helps I am not able to install prey.So how can I install prey on my Ubuntu.

P.S.-I have dual booted my laptop with windows 10.

Comment: 2 things: you have the i386 version (32 bit). You will be better off picking a 64bit version. 2. Why not use USC to install the DEB? USC will also install dependencies if possible. And a comment/tip: anything after "This error comes then I use" has nothing to do with the question and could be removed making it a lot better to read ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind thnx for tip and could u tell what's usc and where can I get 64 bit version,because on the download page there is only one file that's mentioned above.

Comment: https://preyproject.com/blog/page/4?lang=es%2Fdownload

Comment: I had the same problem and I've been unable to solve it. I've downloaded the 64-bit version and tried with `dpkg -i ...` but my installation seems unsuccessful (install messages say Ok, but I can't execute `prey`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the 64-bit .deb file from

> preyproject.com/blog/page/4?lang=es%2Fdownload

then to install it go to the directory containing .deb file and run

> sudo dpkg -i prey_1.5.0_amd64.deb

in terminal,the installation will start.

Answer (score 6):

You will be better off picking the [64-bit version](https://preyproject.com/blog/page/4?lang=es%2Fdownload). That would prevent all the dependencies.

Also when downloading a .DEB you should let Ubuntu Software Center (USC) have it installed. All you need to do is doubleclick the file from Nautilus. If there are any dependencies USC will attempt to install them for you. "dpkg" will not.

Comment: Installation from USC failed giving error:   'Installing init scripts.

(process:6179): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
 Using the fallback 'C' locale.
No protocol specified

(gksu:6179): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
dpkg: error processing package prey (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1'

Comment: @Rinzwid I don't know if you actually installed it but USC is giving error while installing it so using sudo dpkg -i prey_1.5.0_amd64.deb actually solved the problem. So please edit your answer accordingly so I can accept it.